# using else if in a R shiny app

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny

I have a simple sample size calculator shiny app im trying to build that I cant seem to figure out.

the inputs consist of 1 numerical input and a series of radio buttons. 
Im trying to have a different calculation carried dependent on which radiop button is selected

```
   ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("alpha version of sample size calculator"),

  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput(
      "expn",
      "Please enter total number of reports received",
      1,
      min = 0,
      max = 1000000
    ),
    radioButtons(
      inputId = "'QC_Type'",
      label = "QC Type",
      choices = c(
        "Overall" = "a",
        "Solicited" ="b",
        "Spontaneous" = "c",
        "Clinical Trial"="d",
        "Literature"= "e"
      ) 
    )
  ),
  mainPanel (
    p ("Your required sample size is"),
    textOutput("results"))
))

server <- function (input, output) {
  A1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.3)*(1-0.3)/(0.05*0.05)
  B1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.32)*(1-0.32)/(0.05*0.05)
  C1 <-  (1.96*1.96)*(0.35)*(1-0.35)/(0.05*0.05)
  D1 <-  (1.96*1.96)*(0.26)*(1-0.26)/(0.05*0.05)
  E1 <-  (1.96*1.96)*(0.36)*(1-0.36)/(0.05*0.05)
  options(digits=2)
  if (input$QC_Type=="a") {
    output$results <- renderText({
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(A1)/(input$expn+(A1)+1))
    })
  } else if (input$QC_Type=="b") {
    output$results <- renderText({
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(B1)/(input$expn+(B1)+1))
    })
  } else if (input$QC_Type=="c") {
    output$results <- renderText({
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(C1)/(input$expn+(C1)+1))
    })
  } else if (input$QC_Type=="d") {
    output$results <- renderText({
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(D1)/(input$expn+(D1)+1))
    })
  } else if (input$QC_Type=="e") {
    output$results <- renderText({
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(E1)/(input$expn+(E1)+1))
    })
  }
}
```

This however doesn't run and produces an error message mentioning reactive elements.

**Update:**

Thanks for the responses, the R community is incredible :)  - I did indeed look at the suggested thread, while i did indeed notice the similarity my code is attempting to perform a calculation based on a numerical input and a radio button. I tried the following of including the logic in the render functions:

```
       server <- function (input, output) {
  options(digits=2)
  output$results <- renderText({
    x <- reactive({input$QC_Type})
    A1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.3)*(1-0.3)/(0.05*0.05)
    B1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.32)*(1-0.32)/(0.05*0.05)
    C1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.35)*(1-0.35)/(0.05*0.05)
    D1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.26)*(1-0.26)/(0.05*0.05)
    E1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.36)*(1-0.36)/(0.05*0.05)
     if (x()=="a") {  
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(A1)/(input$expn+(A1)+1))
    } else if (x()=="b") {  
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(B1)/(input$expn+(B1)+1))
    } else if (x()=="c") {  
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(C1)/(input$expn+(C1)+1))
    } else if (x()=="d") {  
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(D1)/(input$expn+(D1)+1))
    } else if (x()=="e") {  
      as.numeric( (input$expn)*(E1)/(input$expn+(E1)+1))
    }

  }

  )
}
```

The app runs but in the main output pane I get a message saying argument is of 0 length as opposed to the desired calculation.

**Update 2**

After some further digging around I realized the "zero length" was due to a missing component in the syntax (req input) My code is currently as follows however no output is now generated - any further guidance would be hugely appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("alpha version of sample size calculator"),

  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput(
      "expn",
      "Please enter total number of reports received",
      1,
      min = 0,
      max = 1000000
    ),
    radioButtons(
      inputId = "'QC_Type'",
      label = "QC Type",
      choices = c(
        "Overall" = 1,
        "Solicited" =2,
        "Spontaneous" = 3,
        "Clinical Trial"=4,
        "Literature"= 5
      ) 
    )
  ),
  mainPanel (
    p ("Your required sample size is"),
    textOutput("results"))
))



## server attempt 5 
server <- function (input, output,session) {
  options(digits=2)
  A1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.3)*(1-0.3)/(0.05*0.05)
  B1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.32)*(1-0.32)/(0.05*0.05)
  C1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.35)*(1-0.35)/(0.05*0.05)
  D1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.26)*(1-0.26)/(0.05*0.05)
  E1 <- (1.96*1.96)*(0.36)*(1-0.36)/(0.05*0.05)
  output$results <- renderText({
    x <- reactive({input$QC_Type}) 
    req(input$QC_Type)
    req(input$expn)
     if (x()==1) {  
     as.character( (input$expn)*(A1)/(input$expn+(A1)+1))
    } else if (x()==2) {  
      as.character( (input$expn)*(B1)/(input$expn+(B1)+1))
    } else if (x()==3) {  
      as.character( (input$expn)*(C1)/(input$expn+(C1)+1))
    } else if (x()==4) {  
      as.character( (input$expn)*(D1)/(input$expn+(D1)+1))
    } else if (x()==5) {  
      as.character( (input$expn)*(E1)/(input$expn+(E1)+1))
    } 

    }


  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server= server)
```

Comment: First of all, try to use CTRL-A, CTRL-I on your code to make it easier for us to understand it.

Comment: Hi Teodor, thanks for your comment - I just followed your suggestion and nothing changed regarding the way the code is displayed. 
Please accept my apologies regarding formatting - I'm slightly new to this :)

Comment: Regarding your problem, you can't use `input$QC_Type` (any input) outside a `render_` function of `reactive()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RStudio - Shiny - Error "Operation not allowed without an active reactive context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639947/rstudio-shiny-error-operation-not-allowed-without-an-active-reactive-contex)

Comment: You need to search more on reactive(). Your question is a duplicate, so the answer to your problem can be found on Stack. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639947/rstudio-shiny-error-operation-not-allowed-without-an-active-reactive-contex?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: CTRL+A and CTRL+I works (only) in Rstudio and it should pretty up your code indent-wise.

Comment: Indenting updated - Thanks @RomanLuštrik

Comment: @TeodorCiuraru Thank you so much for your suggestions - I've attempted to replicate the code in the thread you indicated but I think the contexts are somewhat different and I get the "argument is of length 0" output message in my main pain

Comment: I have a follow up question, I have a similar problem but the code is executed inside the function. In other words I have code which requires if(val == X), else if(val == Y) .... where val is an input$[name] but the code block is hiding inside a function. The Shiny crashes if I try to run this, any ideas how to fix it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually really simple: look at the `inputId` for your `radioButtons`:

```
radioButtons(
  inputId = "'QC_Type'",
  label = "QC Type",
  choices = c(
    "Overall" = 1,
    "Solicited" =2,
    "Spontaneous" = 3,
    "Clinical Trial"=4,
    "Literature"= 5
  ) 
)
```

Just remove the extra set of quotes around `QC_Type` and it will work fine.

**Also:** when Shiny talks about a reactive expression, it doesn't just mean `reactive`. Anything with `reactive`, `observe`, or `render` in the name will count. So there's no need for this line:

```
x <- reactive({input$QC_Type})
```

Since you're inside a reactive expression already (the `renderText`) you can remove that line and use `input$QC_Type` wherever you currently have `x()`

Comment: THANK YOU so much!!! That works fine - might just ask how to limit the output to 2 decimal places as?

Comment: Look at `?round` for a bunch of functions that can do that in different ways